# Nuxtj - Best practice to load all information of users after the authentication process

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

i am not a developer but i am deploying a web application using nuxt and i have a doubt about load all information related to the users once in the application, all the information is managed by vuex. I need to load all information after the authentication process because i am showing a dashboard to the user. I have read and found the next options but i don't know where is the best practice without impact the performance of the application:

1.- Load all information in the same vuex action where the user authenticates. I have an action to validate the user and password and it creates the cookies and token sessions. I can load all information in the same action but the authentication process could be slower. With this option the load of information is executed just once.

2.- Load all information in the main/dashboard component by the fetch function consuming an vuex action (do a dispatch). It works but i am seeing that when i browse to the main/dashboard component the fetch function is always appearing. Load of information should be once after the authentication process.

3.- I also am using the nuxtserverinit to load all information when the users press F5 button or reload the web application but if i do a reload in the main/dashboard component i am seeing nuxtserverinit and fetch functions . I am duplicating resources.

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Loading application content is not a part of authentication process, so it should be separated because of responsibility concerns.

It is a good practice to load content on the page which it is relevant to. Using `fetch` repeats itself, but it is possible to check if content has been loaded inside `fetch` hook and dispatch action only if required state is not present is store.

This way no additional requests are made and information is only loaded after user has been granted access to the dashboard.

Comment: Hi, thansk for your response. How would be the check by fetch hook? Are you referring to a "if" validation for instance?

Comment: That is correct. Checking getters/state for being empty and making requests in such case. It is a simple, but efficient solution. If you are looking into something more automated, there are caching layers for request libraries, which can take care of caching responses. For example, one for axios - [axios-cache-adapter](https://github.com/RasCarlito/axios-cache-adapter).

Comment: Good idea, i am going to try the option and check the library for caching responses.